# How can I fix this problem with my CSS background?

Tags: html, css, background

So, I'm new to HTML. And i got a CSS code for a background I liked.
I want it to be static in the background while my ''content'' scrolls normaly over it.

Is this possible?

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I got the code just as code, like not a background thing I think.

This is my HTML code for it:

```
<div class="blur-container"
style="--blur:12vw;">

<div class="shape" 
  style="--path:polygon(50.9% 37.2%, 43.5% 34.7%, 33.6% 26.1%, 39.2% 10.8%, 26.2% 0.0%, 4.8% 6.4%, 0.0% 30.4%, 20.7% 37.2%, 33.4% 26.3%, 43.2% 34.9%, 45.0% 35.6%, 43.6% 46.4%, 37.8% 59.5%, 21.8% 63.2%, 11.7% 76.1%, 22.9% 91.3%, 47.4% 91.3%, 54.0% 79.0%, 38.0% 59.6%, 43.9% 46.4%, 45.2% 35.5%, 50.9% 37.6%, 56.1% 36.8%, 59.8% 47.6%, 70.3% 61.9%, 87.7% 56.0%, 96.4% 37.4%, 88.6% 15.1%, 63.7% 16.7%, 55.2% 33.6%, 55.9% 36.6%, 50.9% 37.2%);"></div>

<div class="shape" 
  style="--path:polygon(50.9% 37.2%, 43.5% 34.7%, 33.6% 26.1%, 39.2% 10.8%, 26.2% 0.0%, 4.8% 6.4%, 0.0% 30.4%, 20.7% 37.2%, 33.4% 26.3%, 43.2% 34.9%, 45.0% 35.6%, 43.6% 46.4%, 37.8% 59.5%, 21.8% 63.2%, 11.7% 76.1%, 22.9% 91.3%, 47.4% 91.3%, 54.0% 79.0%, 38.0% 59.6%, 43.9% 46.4%, 45.2% 35.5%, 50.9% 37.6%, 56.1% 36.8%, 59.8% 47.6%, 70.3% 61.9%, 87.7% 56.0%, 96.4% 37.4%, 88.6% 15.1%, 63.7% 16.7%, 55.2% 33.6%, 55.9% 36.6%, 50.9% 37.2%);
  --offset:180deg;
  --speed: 6000ms;
  --background: linear-gradient( cyan, blue, green, purple, cyan);
  "></div>
  
</div>
```

and this is my CSS:

```
.blur-container{
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed; /* <= This one */
}

  *, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background: Black;
  
  }
  
  .shape {
    margin: 0 auto;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
    position: relative;
    --width: 100%;
    --scale: 1;
    --opacity: 0.66;
    --top: 0;
    --left:0;
    --path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
    --background: linear-gradient( hotpink, red, orange, yellow, hotpink);
    --offset: 0deg;
    --speed: 8000ms;
    clip-path: var(--path);
    background: var(--background);
    scale: var(--scale);
    opacity: var(--opacity);
    width: var(--width);
    top: var(--top);
    left: var(--left);
    rotate: var(--offset);
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
    animation: turn var(--speed) linear forwards infinite;
  }
  @keyframes turn {
    to {
      rotate: calc( var(--offset) + 1turn);
    }
  }
  
  .blur-container {
    --blur: 40px;
    filter: blur(var(--blur));
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .blur-container > * {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    grid-row: 1/-1;
  }
```

I have my CSS in a CSS file in the header (
My CSS for this part isn't under a like header, its just in the CSS code, isn't in like a { thing like {body} or something.

What I now have is an black background and below the entire page is the animation because i placed it below everything so its better readible.

I don't even know if it is in this state ''behind'' the content or not. Because I want it as a background.

I Tried copy- pasting the code in the main HTML and my CSS style docuument. But It doesn't correcltly work so I want it to be static. It just shows up at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the CSS `position: fixed` attribute to the background wrapper. This will fix its position relative to the user's viewport (i.e. its position remains fixed while the user scrolls through the page's content).

Depending on how you are implementing the rest of the content on the page, you may also need to change some elements' `z-index`s so that the background is correctly positioned behind everything else.

Comment: Hey Luke! Thanks for your answer. Do you have any idea for where to place the position: fixed attribute?